# PDO - beginTransaction() in extended class

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo, extend

I am currently refactoring my code and receiving the following error:

> Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction in...

```
 class Dbh {

    private $serverName;
    private $userName;
    private $password;
    private $dbName;

    public function connect(){

        $this->serverName = "localhost";
        $this->userName = "root";
        $this->password = "password";
        $this->dbName = "rms";
        $this->charset = "utf8";

        $dsn = "mysql:host=" . $this->serverName . ";dbname=" . $this->dbName . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->userName, $this->password); 
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $pdo;
    }

 }


 class General extends Dbh {

     public function putHistory($consultantID, $type, $typeID) {

         $this->connect()->beginTransaction();

         $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO History (consultantID, type, typeID) VALUES (:consultantID, :type, :typeID) ");
         $stmt -> execute(array(':consultantID' => $consultantID, ':type' => $type, ':typeID' => $typeID));

         $this->connect()->commit();
     }

 }

 $GeneralObject = new General;
 $GeneralObject -> putHistory("1", "2", "3");
```

I guess I'm calling the `beginTransaction()`/`commit()` incorrectly in this instance?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Usually an error message points to particular line in the code. Does it this time?

Comment: Every `connect()` makes a new connection, so one doesn't know the `beginTransaction()` of the other.

Comment: Sorry, yes it is specifically referencing the Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction in ...: PDO->commit()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is due to calling `$this->connect()` multiple times, you are calling it 3 times in `putHistory()`. Hence every time a new `$pdo` object is returned. I'd recommend that you call `$this->connect()` only once and store its value in a variable and then call these functions: `beginTransaction()`, `commit()`.

Comment: Thanks rock start - I understand now ...  $connection = $this->connect(); and then reference $connection